# web control deploying in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint

```
protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl_EmpCode.Text = "";
            SPSite newsites = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPWeb webs = newsites.OpenWeb();


            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = string.Format ( "<Query>" +"<Where>"+ "<Eq>"+ "<FieldRef Name='Company_x0020_Code' />"+" <Value Type='Text'>"+ txt_Companycode.Text +"</Value>"+" </Eq>"+" </Where>"+" </Query>");

            SPList list = webs.Lists["Companies"];

            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);


            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                txt_Companycode.Text = "";
                Response.Redirect("Pages/ClaimAccount.aspx");
            }
            else
            {

                lbl_EmpCode.Text = "Company Code is not Matching with the Exisiting Record..!";
                txt_Companycode.Text = "";
                Response.Redirect("Pages/CompanyCodeCheck.aspx");

            }
        }
```

What is wrong with my code? In this code I am getting data from a user through a `TextBox` as a Company Code, then I am comparing with a Sharepoint list. If it matches, go to next page, if not, then stay on the same page and give an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove query tag from the string(query.Query) build the CAML directly from where tag

Comment: query.Query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Company_x0020_Code' /> <Value Type='Text'> txt_Companycode.Text </Value> </Eq> </Where> </Query>";     i have tried this too, but same result.

Comment: try this query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Company_x0020_Code' /> <Value Type='Text'>"+ txt_Companycode.Text"+"</Value> </Eq> </Where>"